# Using CSS3 animations breaks fixed background positioning of all elements in page

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position, css-animations, background-position

I was just working on a web page featuring elements with `fixed` background positioning, and it worked great until I applied **css animations** to a (completely different & irrelevant) element.

I tried removing / re-applying the animations to make sure it was actually the issue, and sure enough, when I add animation, the background positioning (of **every** element on the page) goes static, and works again the moment I remove the anims.

**Is this normal?**

---

Ultimately, I'm looking for a solution that allows for:

- **relatively** positioned,
- **floating** elements (or a least children of similar wrappers)
- to be used with **fixed** background position
- in a web page where CSS3 animations are used,
- compatible with Chrome.

---

Here's with the animations:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wr7X4/5/

And here's without them:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wr7X4/4/

*I've only tested this in Chrome.*

---

**UPDATE**: As shown by one answer, giving the elements with **fixed background positions** `static` positioning causes the elements to retain the behavior of their fixed background when CSS3 animations are active on a page at the expense of the needed relative element positioning.

One would assume that this could be solved by wrapping the involved elements in a relative parent element, but this is not the case.

It would appear that even a grand-child of a relatively positioned element will lose its fixed background positioning if CSS3 animations (or transitions) are **active** *anywhere* on the page.

---

Here's **with** the **static** positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wr7X4/6/

Here's the static positioning **with a relative wrapper**, *floating*:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wr7X4/7/

Here's the above *without CSS3 animations active*:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wr7X4/8/

And something that I just discovered, if I remove `float:left` from the wrapper:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wr7X4/9/

Which makes it work just fine!

---

Comment: Can you add your code to your post and provide a JSFiddle ?

Comment: Its a very big web page.. I'll build a fiddle of a test scenario

Comment: You could have the courtesy to support firefox ...

Comment: Ah firefox? I was deving with chrome. Sorry about that! @aloisdg

Comment: This doesn't work with FF or IE at all, which I'd highly recommend against. Looks pretty sweet in Chrome though!

Comment: @AndyM To speed up the initial result, I support chrome, and then once the project is complete I run the css through Nettuts's Prefixr add that does a great job of making everything extremely cross browser.

Comment: I've been looking at that and it looks like the website is down. Has it been taken up again?

Comment: @AndyM yes, weirdly it is down for a while now (An app owned and run by a company like Nettuts, down?) - looks like I'll be adopting Sass

Comment: @AndyM https://twitter.com/nettuts/status/439046862885363712

Comment: Edit: https://twitter.com/jeffrey_way/status/453987026648723456 - tweeted the guy at Nettuts that ran it and its gone for good. @AndyM

Comment: Damn. Auto is nice, but it requires node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **CSS3 Animations** breaking fixed background positioning in Chrome.

The closest that I have gotten to my *requested* answer is a workaround that allows for:

- **relatively** positioned,
- **fixed** background elements,
- in a web page where **CSS3 animations** are used,
- compatible with Chrome.

But **NOT** for:

- `fixed-background` elements to **ultimately** *be given the **behavior** of* `float` positioning.

---

**To *work-around* this Chrome bug:**

1. Place a wrapper around `fixed background-position` elements with the class `relative-wrapper`.
2. Give the relative-wrapper class the style `position: relative`. (And any other styles you need to give it, such as width or height. Just no **float**.
3. And finally, **ironically**, give the elements with `fixed background-position` the style `float: left` (or any float). Note: Float positioning will make your elements act and size differently.

---

*You should Google CSS float positioning if you don't already know how it causes elements to behave. However, since the purpose of this question was to figure out how to make relative and float positioning work on fixed-background elements in a page with CSS3 animations, I'm going to assume that you can handle that.*

---

Notice earlier, I said that the `fixed background-position` elements could not

> **ultimately** *be given the **behavior** of* `float` positioning.

This is because no matter what you do, you'll have to wrap the floated elements in a wrapper with non-float positioning or the `fixed` background position stays **broken**. It just so happens that the element ***inside*** the relative wrapper needs to be given `float` positioning to keep its fixed background positioning.

---

I don't know why this works, but it *does*.

Here's the [JSFiddle, see for yourself.](http://jsfiddle.net/Wr7X4/9/)

---

### **CSS3 Transition** activity: same effect on fixed background positioning

I don't have the time to add JSFiddle examples, but it's worth noting that this work-around also solves breakage of `fix-background position` in elements when **CSS3 Transitions** are **active** in the web page.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but adding `z-idex: -1` did work. This is really an annoying bug.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
.outside-board{
    //try to change position to
    position:static;
}
```

Comment: This does fix two of my fix-positioned backgrounds, and leaves the other static, oddly, can you explain why/ how this works?

Comment: This does cause alternate problems, such as the fact that I can't use z-index on the elements. I can, of course, use a wrapper to fix that, if need be.

Comment: Edit to that: I can't use a wrapper either! It seems that if the element is the grand-child of any relatively positioned element, even with its own static positioning, it will not retain the fixed background position behavior. Why would CSS3 animations on an unrelated element have such an effect?